# Different Firebird query results from dev machine and production server (cyrillic characters)

Tags: encoding, firebird

I'm connecting to a remote Firebird 2.1 DB Server and i'm querying data that contains some cyrillic characters togeather with some latin ones.

The problem is that when i deploy the app on the production system, the cyrillic characters look like this: **ÂÚÇÄÓØÍÀ**. In addition, when trying to log what comes in from the DB, the cyrillic content is just **skipped in the log file** (i.e. i'm not seeing the **ÂÚÇÄÓØÍÀ** at all).

At this point i'm not sure whether i'm getting **inconsistent data** from the DB **OR** the production environment **can't recognize those characters** for some reason.

I've been wandering about for quite some time now and ran out of ideas, so any hints would be great.

**The Dev machine** that i use runs Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. My system locale is Bulgarian

**The Production Server** is accessed via Paralles Plesk Panel, and i'm not sure what's underneath.

Comment: What is your connection characterset? If you didn't specify any connection character set, almost all drivers connect with `NONE` and use the default system character set to convert the received bytes.

Comment: I haven't specified any charset in the connString. I've previously checked the charset of the remote DB and it is the default one - 'NONE'

Comment: Then try WIN1251 and see if it solve your problem.

Comment: Yup, that solved it. Thanks Andrej!

Answer (score 2):

If you did not specify any character set in your connection properties, then almost all Firebird drivers default to connection character set `NONE`. This means that Firebird will send the bytes of strings as they are stored in the database without any conversion, on the other side the driver will use the default system character set to convert those bytes to strings. If you use multiple systems with various default system character sets you will get different results.

You should always explicitly specify a connection characterset (`WIN1251` in your case), unless you really know what you are doing.